# Focus color remains after item is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, .net-4.5

I have made my own ComboBox control in order to use items with custom background and foreground colors. The ComboBox is also defined as DropDownList.

```
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public CustomComboBox()
    {
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
        e.DrawBackground();
        var item = ((ResultColor)Items[e.Index]);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(item.BackgroundColor, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Name, Font, item.Color, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

If it matters, my ResultColor class is as below:

```
public class ResultColor
{
    public ResultColor(int id, string name, Brush color, Brush backgroundColor)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Color = color;
        BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
    public Brush BackgroundColor { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

The initial issue I had, was that when hovering through the items focused had no color in the list.

Further looking around, I found out that I can use the `e.State` to check the current item state and change the color according, so now I do this:

```
var brush = (e.State & DrawItemState.Focus) == DrawItemState.Focus ?
             Brushes.DodgerBlue : 
             item.BackgroundColor;
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds.X,
                         e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, 
                         e.Bounds.Height);
```

This way it will properly have a different color as I hover thru the items, unhappily, after I click/select an item and the combobox closes, that item will retain the focus color rather than the item color, same goes for `Selected` state, and `HotLight` doesn't even seem to work as it never triggers.

**How can I do so it will only use the focus color while its hovering on the items while the dropdown is open and use the proper item color when an item has been selected?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, apparently the issue was not with the draw but rather with the control being focused.

What I did as a work around was to override on my `CustomComboBox` the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, like this:

```
protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    if (Focused)
    {
        Parent.Focus();
    }
}
```

And make it set focus to the parent control, thus making the item have its original color once selected.

IF there is a proper solution, other than using a parent control to set focus to, I would love to hear.